# Is there a way to set default job priority by the user who launches the job?

Tags: hadoop, hive

There are serval users in my Hadoop cluser, for example commerce and latency. Since commerce data is more important than website latency data, I want to set priority of jobs launched by user commerce HIGH, while jobs of user latency LOW. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There will be a proper way.  But as a hack, you could force users to use a bash script that wraps hadoop with `-Dmapred.job.priority=LOW` then set the permissions accordingly - similarly for HIGH.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Fair Scheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html)? I haven't used it myself but it seems it should do the job.